# C# or Visual C# both are same?

Tags: c#

In many place on internet or book I read about these two words interchangeably. Both are same or different?

Comment: Hopefully useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C_Sharp

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx37x362.aspx

Comment: You will also see C-Sharp for C#

Answer (score 5):

**Visual C#** is a development tool published by *Microsoft*, to develop applications based around the **C#** *language*.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. :)

Comment: Also, just to note - although there is Mono and it's relatives, _most_ C# programming happens in Visual C#, so it's often used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

C# is a programming language that can be implemented in various ways. Visual C# is Microsoft's implementation of C# through their .NET frameworks. Anyway, if you're like 99% of the people using C#, then you are using Microsoft's implementation.

Comment: Also - could it be that "Visual C#" is actually just the part of Visual Studio IDE that is responsible for C# editing 'n stuff?

Comment: Command line compiler's name is `csc` not `vcsc`. +1 to @Vilx-

Comment: @L.B - please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kx37x362. `Visual C# is an implementation of the C# language by Microsoft.`

Comment: @jskiles1 Did I say anything different?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. There isn't really any product named "Visual C#"

It may be a mixup, either with *Visual Studio* that is the IDE for Microsoft's implementation of C#, with *Visual C# Express* which is a free limited version of the IDE only supporting development in C#, or with *Visual Basic* which is another language used in the same IDE.

Comment: [VISUAL C# 2010 EXPRESS](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express)

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.